# Visual Studio Community 2015 MySQL data source not appearing

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-community

I am trying to integrate MySQL database with my ASP.NET project. I have seen many tutorials and did the following

1. Added the MySql.Data, MySql.DataEntity.EF6 and MySql.Web into the project.
2. change the web config file to connect to the mysql database

   ```
   <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
     <clear />
       <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
   </system.data>
   ```

Note: the snippet was suggested in a tutorial that can be found in
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcfCinE53qA)

After doing all that when I try to add data source with the help of AOD.NET entity data model, the data source for MySql option does not appear.

[image: Data source Option]

I am using

1. Visual Studio Community 2015
2. MySQL for visual studio 1.2.7
3. Connector/NET 6.10.6

How can i solve the problem? Does it have something to do with the versions and compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there isn't a "MySql for Visual Studio" for Connector/NET 6.10.6

Uninstall Connector/NET 6.10.6
Install Connector/NET 6.9.8 [MySQL Connector/Net (Archived Versions)](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)

Comment: Thank for the reply. I will try this soon.